# How do I redirect to different pages from a drop down list in php?

Tags: php

When users come to my home page I want them to select which page they want to go to.  So, for instance sports, trivia, etc. from a drop down list.  How would I get it to redirect to the specific page that is selected using php?  This should be simple but I haven't found the solution by searching google.

Comment: call javascript function inside onSelect, try this - http://www.crowderassoc.com/javascript/dropdownlist.html

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript if you want the redirection to occur right at the time they select a page. If you want it to occur when they click a "GO" button (submit the form) then you can achieve this with PHP.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be done with a submit button so it should be php.  I know nothing of javascript.

Comment: Can you guys post a sample code using php?

Comment: @user917469: you should learn javascript and PHP first, at least basics

Comment: COde is given in my shared link, check above comment. You don't need to do this type of things at server side. Do it at client side it better

Comment: @user917469 - If you want a list box or `<select>` with "links", you need javascript, as the `<select>` element has no inherent ability to trigger navigation. Spend awhile on google, show most recent results, and search for HTML, PHP, Javascript, and/or jQuery. You'll learn quickly that there's alot that can be accomplished with a little elbow grease. If you don't, nobody can or will help you (*any more than anyone already has*)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_POST['select']){
   header("Location: ".$_POST['select']);
}
?>
<form type="post" action="">
    <select name="select">
       <option value="http://link1.com">link1</option>   
       <option value="http://link2.com">link2</option>
       <option value="http://link3.com">link3</option>
       <option value="http://link4.com">link4</option>
       <option value="http://link5.com">link5</option>
    </slect>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: That's not a dropdown menu.  I mean something where when you click the list opens up.  Otherwise it only shows the top option.

Comment: @user917469: yes, it does. please learn to press F5 before commenting, I edited it 2 minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

PHP run serverside and thus can't handle the redirect in the HTML client. However, you can use PHP to dynamicly print your dropdown as needed. Then you add a **onSelect** function to your dropdown that either does the redirect itself using **javascript:window.location="foobar.html"** where foobar.html is the page you want to redirect to. Or you make the **onSelect** fire a javascript function within which you handle the actual redirect and can look at several elements in your page to decide where to redirect the client to.

Good luck!

Comment: I see.  Thanks for clearing that up.  So I have to use javascript then.  I thought I was going crazy as I tried different ways to do it with just php and html alone.

Comment: _"PHP run serverside and thus can't handle the redirect in the HTML client."_ It is not 100% clear what you are trying to say, but I would state that PHP does redirect via headers.

Comment: @Shef - I agree with that caveat also, however; the answer both you and genesis have posted, while likely what the OP was looking for, is such a gross misuse of PHP (*or any server-side technology*), that I'm leaving the room to smoke :P

Comment: @Bracketworks: I agree with you, I stated that to the OP. It's those tough coders who want to re-invent the wheel, we can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Shef - Yea, I also don't think OP is aware that posting values through a form, in order to facilitate navigation, is also an accessibility and SEO nightmare.

Comment: [This article](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-select.html) pretty much explains how to do it.

Comment: On a html request PHP can construct and send back a header causing the browser to redirect to another page. It can NOT actually cause a redirect in itself in the same way that javascript can. It can merely return a header. So PHP can NOT run client side and do redirects in the browser based on a given selection. You could most likely send an ajax request to the php server when an item is selected and handle that but that would still require javascript to handle the catching of the selection and sending the ajax request. So it might as well be used to do the redirect straight away.

Comment: @inquam: I don't know about html requests, I do know about HTTP ones though. A header `Location` is a parameter of the HTTP protocol, which every HTTP-compliant browser must follow. I do agree with you that it's the client side language which handles the events and user interactions, but I beg to differ on the idea that PHP can't do redirects.

Answer (score -1):

You should think of avoiding drop downs to handle this, and use links instead. However, if you are really into it, here is the solution:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['redirect'])){
    header('Location: '.$_POST['link']);
    exit;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="link">
       <option value="http://www.site.com/page1">Page 1</option>
       <option value="http://www.site.com/page2">Page 2</option>
       <option value="http://www.site.com/page3">Page 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="redirect" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Comment: In answering the question, you should make no assumption that links are possible as an alternative to the dropdown